# Django Debug Toolbar не отображается панель

Tags: python, django

Установил Django Debug Toolbar в соответствии с [инструкцией](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) однако панель управления не отображается при загрузке страницы, хотя при просмотре исходного кода страницы элементы видны. В чем может быть проблема?

В исходном коде есть блок:

```
<div class="djdt-hidden" id="djDebugToolbar">
```

Соответственно если убрать из класса hidden панель появляется, но в нерабочем состоянии (Django 3.1.7)

Ошибка в консоли (файл toolbar.js):

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Answer (score 1):

В файл settings.py добавить:

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
```